# Python - How to search for a zip file that resides in an iframe on https

Tags: python, iframe, web, https, unzip

- Python - 2.7.5
- Google Chrome

First off I am self taught coder and will accept any critique and/or suggestions to any of my posted codes below.  This issue has been a joy to work through because I love challenging myself but I am afraid I have hit a brick wall and need some guidance.  I will be as detailed as possible below to fully explain the overall picture of my script and then show where I am at with the actual issue that is explained in the title.

I am putting together a script that will go out and download data automatically, upzip, and export to a GDB.  We serve a wide region of users and have a very large enterprise SDE setup containing large amount of public data that we have to go out and search and update for our end users.  Most of our data is updated monthly by local government entities and we have to go out and search for the data manually, download, unzip, QAQC, etc.  I am wanting to put a script a together that will automate the first part of this process by going out and downloading all my data for me and exporting to a local GDB, from there I can QAQC everything and upload to our SDE for our users to access.

The process has been pretty straight forward so far until I got to this issue I have before me.  My script will search a webpage for specific keywords and find the relevant link and begin the download.  For this post I will use two examples, one that works and one that is currently giving me issues.  What works is my function for searching and downloading the Metro GIS dataset and below shows my current process for finding this. So far all http websites I have included will use the posted function below.  Like Metro is being shown I plan on having a defined function for each group of data.

```
import requests, zipfile, StringIO, time, arcpy, urllib2, urlparse
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

workPath = -- #The output GDB
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
gdbName = "GlobalSDEUpdate_" + timestr
gdbPath = workPath + "\\" + gdbName + ".gdb"

class global_DataFinder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        object.__init__(self)
        self.gdbSetup()
        self.metro()

    def gdbSetup(self):       
        arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workPath, gdbName)

    def fileDownload(self, key, url, dlPath, dsName):
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        urlList = []

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        soup.prettify()

        for link in soup.findAll('a', href = True):
            if not 'http://' in link['href']:
                if urlparse.urljoin(url, link['href']) not in urlList:
                    zipDL = urlparse.urljoin(url, link['href'])
                    if zipDL.endswith(".zip"):
                        if key in zipDL:
                            urlList.append(zipDL)        

        for x in urlList:
            print x
            r = requests.get(x, stream=True)
            z = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(r.content))        
            z.extractall(dlPath)        

        arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(gdbPath, dsName)
        arcpy.env.workspace = dlPath
        shpList = []

        for shp in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
            shpList.append(shp)

        arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(shpList, (gdbPath + "\\" + dsName))

        del shpList[:]

    def metro(self):
        key = "METRO_GIS_Data_Layers"
        url = "http://www.ridemetro.org/Pages/NewsDownloads.aspx"
        dlPath = -- *#Where my zipfiles output to*  
        dsName = "Metro"

        self.fileDownload(key, url, dlPath, dsName)

global_DataFinder()
```

As you can see above this is the method I started with using Metro as my first testing point and this is currently working great.  I was hoping all my sites going forward would like this but when I got to FEMA I ran into an issue.

The website [National Flood Hazard Layer (NFHL) Status](http://www.floodmaps.fema.gov/NFHL/status.shtml) hosts floodplain data for many counties across the country is available for free to any who wish to use it.  When arriving at the website you will see that you can search for the county you want, then the table queries out the search, then you can simply click and download the county you desire.  When checking the source this is what I came across and noticed its in an *iframe*.

When accessing the iframe source link through Chrome and checking the png source url this is what you get - **https://hazards.fema.gov/femaportal/NFHL/searchResult**

Now here is where my problem lies, unlike http sites I have quickly learned that accessing a secured https site and scraping the page is different especially when its using javascript to show the table.  I have spent hours searching through forums and tried different python packages like selenium, mechanize, requests, urllib, urllib2, and I seem to always hit a dead-end before I can securely establish a connection and parse the webpage and search for my counties zipfile. The code below shows the closest I have gotten and shows the error code I am getting.

*(I always test in a separate script and then when it works I bring it over to my main script, so thats why this code snippet below is separated from my original)*

```
import urllib2, httplib, socket, ssl
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.floodmaps.fema.gov/NFHL/status.shtml"

def test():  
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    urlList = []

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    soup.prettify()

    for link in soup.findAll("iframe", src=True):
        r = urllib2.urlopen(link['src'])
        iFrame = link['src']
        print iFrame

def connect_patched(self):
    "Connect to a host on a given (SSL) port."

    sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port),
                                    self.timeout, self.source_address)
    if self._tunnel_host:
        self.sock = sock
        self._tunnel()
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file,
                                ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv2)

httplib.HTTPSConnection.connect = connect_patched

test()
```

**Error I get when running this test**

*urllib2.URLError: urlopen error [Errno 6] _ssl.c:504: TLS/SSL connection has been closed*

I am hoping a more experienced coder can see what I have done and tell me if my current methods are the way to go and if so how to get past this final error and parse the datatable properly.

***Working Edits with @crmackey***

```
import requests
import os
import zipfile
from pyquery import PyQuery
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning, InsecurePlatformWarning, SNIMissingWarning

import httplib
httplib.HTTPConnection._http_vsn = 10
httplib.HTTPConnection._http_vsn_str = 'HTTP/1.0'

# disable ssl warnings (we are not verifying SSL certificates at this time...future ehnancement?)
for warning in [SNIMissingWarning, InsecurePlatformWarning, InsecureRequestWarning]:
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(warning)

def download_zips(out_path):
    url = 'http://www.floodmaps.fema.gov/NFHL/status.shtml'
    download_prefix = 'https://hazards.fema.gov/femaportal/NFHL'
    pq = PyQuery(requests.get(url, verify=False).content) #verify param important for SSL
    src = pq.find('iframe').attr('src')
    pq = PyQuery(requests.get(src, verify=False).content)
    table = pq.find('table')

    for a in table.find('a'):
        href = a.attrib.get('href')
        print href
        url = '/'.join([download_prefix, href])
        print url
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True, verify=False)
        out_zip = os.path.join(out_path, href.split('=')[-1])
        with open(out_zip, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(1024 *16): #grab 1KB at a time
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
        print 'downloaded zip: "{}"'.format(href.split('=')[-1])


out_path = r"C:\Users\barr\Desktop\Test"
download_zips(out_path)
```

All I added was the httplib and changed the HTTPConnection at the top.  That allowed to me connect to the site using your script.  Now here is the current problem.  I am only getting 1 zip file in my out_path, and the zip file is empty.  I checked the printed source in the debug window and its showing its trying to download the TERRITORY OF THE VIRGIN ISLAND zip file from the table so it looks like its trying but its not downloading anything. After it outputs that one empty zip file the script finishes and brings up no further error messages.  I temporarily removed your lines that unzipped the file because they were returning an error since the folder was empty.

Comment: I saw this on GIS Stack Exchange but didn't get the answer added before the question was put on hold.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the zip files downloaded by using the requests module and also opted for using [PyQuery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery) instead of Beautiful Soup.  I think the issue you were facing has to do with the SSL cert validation, where the `requests` module will allow you to skip checking the certificate if you set the `verify` parameter to `False`.

The function below will download all the zip files and unzip them, from there, you can import the shapefiles into your geodatabase:

```
import requests
import os
import zipfile
from pyquery import PyQuery
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning, InsecurePlatformWarning, SNIMissingWarning

# disable ssl warnings (we are not verifying SSL certificates at this time...future ehnancement?)
for warning in [SNIMissingWarning, InsecurePlatformWarning, InsecureRequestWarning]:
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(warning)

def download_zips(out_path):
    url = 'http://www.floodmaps.fema.gov/NFHL/status.shtml'
    download_prefix = 'https://hazards.fema.gov/femaportal/NFHL'
    pq = PyQuery(requests.get(url, verify=False).content) #verify param important for SSL
    src = pq.find('iframe').attr('src')
    pq = PyQuery(requests.get(src, verify=False).content)
    table = pq.find('table')
    for a in table.find('a'):
        href = a.attrib.get('href')
        url = '/'.join([download_prefix, href])
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True, verify=False)
        out_zip = os.path.join(out_path, href.split('=')[-1])
        with open(out_zip, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(1024 *16): #grab 1KB at a time
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
        print 'downloaded zip: "{}"'.format(href.split('=')[-1])

        # do more stuff like unzip?
        unzipped = out_zip.split('.zip')[0]
        with zipfile.Zipfile(out_zip, 'r') as f:
            f.extractall(unzipped)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time in putting this together @crmackey.  I copied your script over to a py file, added an out_path variable and tested in and I am getting this error.  requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 5122 more expected)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 5122 more expected))

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with my connection at the office?  The error is happing at - pq = PyQuery(requests.get(src, verify=False).content)

Comment: That is strange, it could be.  Did it download any zip files? Or did it fail on the first one?

Comment: well I made one change to the code in attempts to get past that error and it seemed to work but now I have another strange thing happening.  I will make an edit now in my original post that shows it.

Comment: new edits in the original post should be visible now tagged with your name.